# Email format validation before sending email ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to adapt a code that I have found on the internet to only perform a sanity check on the email field of my contact form before the message gets send (I use `type="text" required/` for the other fields).

I came up with the code below, but that doesn't work (nothing happens when I click the form "submit button")

What is the issue?

Many thanks,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactfrm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#email").val();

        function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        };
        if (isValidEmail(email)) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sendmessagetest.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('button[name="submit"]').hide();
                    $('.error').hide()
                    $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
 <form class="clearfix" id="contactfrm" method="post" name="contactfrm">
    <div class="tagbox wow fadeInRightBig"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Formulaire de contact
    </div>
    <input class="_input-1 input-40pc" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Votre Prénom" type="text" required/>
    <input class="_input-1 input-40pc" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Votre nom de famille" type="text" required/>
    <input class="_input-2 input-40pc" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Votre adresse e-mail" type="text" required/>
    <input class="_input-1 input-40pc" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Numéro de téléphone" type="text">
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Votre message"></textarea>
    <button class="wow fadeInUp" name="submit" type="submit" value="Envoyer"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> ENVOYER&nbsp;</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Please write the HTML that you're using too. My assumption is that the issue is hidden somewhere there.

Comment: Thanks. HTML updated.

Comment: `data: dataString,` - Is the `dataString` defined somewhere else? Because I can't see it in your code example...

Comment: Thanks Artur. No, nowhere. Is this required? Thanks

Comment: Yes it is! :-) This is the data that you send to the server... More than this, without defining it you get a JS error: *"Uncaught ReferenceError: dataString is not defined"*. Try this: `var dataString = $(this).serialize();` right after `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Also, move the `function isValidEmail(emailAddress)` method outside of the form `submit` event handler. It's pointless to redefine this method on every single submission.

Comment: Thanks. When you say outside the "submit event handler", do you mean just before "if (isValidEmail(email))" ? Thanks.

Comment: No. Before `$("#contactfrm").submit(function(e){` - this is the *"submit event handler"*

Comment: Thanks, works great! Can you put that as an answer rather than a comment? One last question, I've noticed that if for instance I put an incorrect password in my phpfile (I'm using PHPMailer) I'm still getting a "message sent sucesssfully" below my form. Is there a way to also capture the potential error messages returned by PHPMailer before displaying the Success message? Thanks

Comment: And this is how my phpmailer ends: $response = array();
if(!$mail->send()) {
  $response = array('message'=>"Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo, 'status'=> 0);
} else {
  $response = array('message'=>"Message has been sent successfully", 'status'=> 1);
}

/* send content type header */
header('Content-Type: application/json');

/* send response as json */
echo json_encode($response);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code produce JS error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: dataString is not defined

because you have missing `dataString` variable definition (which should be the data that you send to the server).

*On a side note* - move the `isValidEmail(emailAddress)` method outside of the form `submit` event handler. It's pointless to redefine this method on every single submission of the form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Move the method outside of the form submit event handler:
    function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    };

    $("#contactfrm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // define dataString variable (serialize the form):
        var dataString = $(this).serialize();

        var email = $("#email").val();       
        if (isValidEmail(email)) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sendmessagetest.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('button[name="submit"]').hide();
                    $('.error').hide();
                    $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
        }

        // no need for this because you have used e.preventDefault();
        // return false;
    });

});
```

---

As for the comment below the question - you can try the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendmessagetest.php",
    data: dataString,
    // specify the data type:
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        // check server response:
        if(response.status){
            $('button[name="submit"]').hide();
            $('.error').hide();
            $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
        }else{
            $('.success').hide();
            $('.error').text(response.message).fadeIn(1000);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Artur. With the new $.ajax section that you provided, the page reloads when user click "send". Is this a syntax error the way I added it? See https://jsfiddle.net/u8sydzas/ Many thanks,

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, one small detail: it doesn't show any error message when the e-mail address does not meet the requirements in the email validation function (nothing happens when I click "send", which is good, but no message). Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try This one:

```
function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this code I'm constantly getting a message that the email is no valid. Weird.